# jQuery autocomplete: autocomplete object at runtime

Tags: javascript, debugging, jquery-autocomplete

Maybe a trivial question, but I wonder if is it possible to *inspect* the current autocomplete object bound to an element.

Let say autocomplete is bound an input element:

```
<input id="myInput" />
<script>
$( "#myInput" ).autocomplete({
    source: [/* whatever */]
});
</script>
```

For example I tried something like this in the `Chrome debugger`:

```
$('#myInput').autocomplete.source
$('#myInput').autocomplete.delay
```

But each item returns `undefined`.

**Question**

Is it possible to access the **whole** autocomplete object at runtime?

Comment: [Why do you want to do this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the array being passed to the autocomplete?

Why not put it in a global variable first?

If I have misunderstood, then this may be useful:

[Autocomplete Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834688/autocomplete-source)

Comment: no, I mean the whole autocomplete object, not only the `source` member.

Comment: note that `autocomplete` is a function; do you mean the object you pass to `autocomplete`?

Comment: @Kos. I wonder if is there an object at runtime that store all the autocomplete configuration.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say so. You can fork the code and make it available.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly trivial:

```
var autocompleteObject = $( "#myInput" ).autocomplete({
    source: [/* whatever */]
});
```

You should be able to inspect autocompleteObject object. :-)

Comment: I tried, but the .autocomplete() method returns the target object. In the example, the input object is returned.